# Regex to match comma not between grouping symbols

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need a regular expression that will match a comma that is NOT between either a '[' and ']' or '(' and ')' or '{' and '}'. Other grouping symbols do not matter. I have tried to figure it out but I cannot come up with anything that accomplishes this.

The regex is to be used with the PHP preg_split function to split a string on the matched commas.

An example string containing commas and grouping symbols:

```
<div>Hello<div>,@func[opt1,opt2],{,test},blahblah
```

The string should split up as follows:

```
1: '<div>Hello<div>'
2: '@func[opt1,opt2]'
3: '{,test}'
4: 'blahblah'
```

And I just thought of this, but at this point all grouping symbols are guaranteed to have matching symbols, incase that helps.

Any help would be GREATLY appriciated =)

Answer (score 10):

Actually it is not impossible to get this splitting done. Consider this code:

```
$str = '<div>Hello<div>,(foo,bar),@func[opt1,opt2],{,test},blahblah';
$arr = preg_split('~([^,]*(?:{[^}]*}|\([^)]*\)|\[[^]]*])[^,]*)+|,~', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($arr);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "<div>Hello<div>"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "(foo,bar)"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "@func[opt1,opt2]"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "{,test}"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "blahblah"
}
```

Comment: @alex: Thanks, Coming from such a subject matter expert, it means a lot.

Comment: You may want to have the capturing group repeated, and maybe allow other characters as well - consider `1,[foo]and{bar},3`. Hmm, in fact, the OP agrees with me, the expected output is `@func[opt1,opt2]`. Another issue that I never get right is empty tokens. If you parse columns, you want to keep them: `1,,,4`. Just thoughts.

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks for your comments. I corrected my answer to make it repeating. Please check, not it captures `@func[opt1,opt2]`. Also since I am using `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag therefore for string `1,,4` it will output `1` and `4`. However if you remove this flag it prints `1`, `""`, `""`, `4` correctly.

Comment: Hmm, your solution looks good to me. I managed to get it working without a regex but I think I'll replace it with this as it's probably more stable. Thank you :)

Comment: Wow. Really interesting solution you have here. +1

Comment: Wow that was epic, always intrigued by your quality answers. Upvoting. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done in a regular expression.  The basic problem is that this requires variable length negative look-behinds (disallow any [({ that is not followed by a ])}), and that isn't a capability which RE currently has.