# What is the regex to find and replace commas not surrounded by curly braces with commas surrounded by curly braces using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match comma not between grouping symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132911/regex-to-match-comma-not-between-grouping-symbols)

What is the regex to find and replace commas not surrounded by curly braces on both sides with commas surrounded by curly braces on both sides using preg_replace?

Example:

```
$subject = "blah.blah,{blah.blah},blah.blah";

$result = "{blah.blah},{blah.blah},{blah.blah}";
```

Avoid this and other unwanted variations:

```
$result = "{blah.blah},{{blah.blah}},{blah.blah}";
```

Comment: @Asad what?  preg_replace can't find and replace?

Comment: @mario my question is somewhat similar but not an exact duplicate of the question you mentioned

Comment: Sorry for duplicating a previous question, but also thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(?<=^|,)([^{},]+)(?=$|,)/", '{$1}', "blah.blah,{blah.blah},blah.blah");
```

Comment: Use apostrophes instead of double quotes on `{$1}` or it may return a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer works but there is a better regular expression cause look-behind und look-after are to expensive for the machine:

```
preg_replace('/(^|,)([^{},]+)($|,)/', '$1{$2}$3', 'blah.blah,{blah.blah},blah.blah');
```

Comment: I tried this one as well and it worked for the example string I provided.  Thanks for letting me know about the expensiveness of look-behind and look-after.